# Dilemna : prevent StackOverflowException or improve user experience?

Tags: android, workflow-activity

In my application, I have 2 list activities which can start one or the other by clicking on their items.

```
|--Activity1--|           |--Activity2--|           |--Activity1--|
|   item11    | ->click-> |   item21    |           |   item21    | ->click-> ...
|   item12    |           |   item22    | ->click-> |   item12    | 
|   item13    |           |   item23    |           |   item13    |
|-------------|           |-------------|           |-------------|
```

So if the user clicks too much, he can fill all the stack and the system will throw a `StackOverFlowException` won't it ?

The solution I chose then was to tag these 2 activities with `noHistory="true"`, but now I regret that the user can't navigate between these 2 activities with the back button.

Can someone help me to find a better alternative ?

Thanks in advance

> **EDIT: to be more comprehensive, let's explain what is this activity workflow goal :**

I have a database which store a list of names linked to a list of days in a year. A name can be linked to multiple days, and same thing a day can be linked to multiple names.

```
the database schema 

|  names  |---< n, m >---|  days  |
```

**So this activity workflow is a kind of database navigator :**

- `Activity1` is the `NameListActivity`, it displays a list of names linked to a specific day.
- `Activity2` is the `DateListActivity`, it displays a list of days linked to a specific name.

When user clicks on an item (a *name*) of the `NameListActivity`, the `DateListActivity` is started with the list of days linked to the clicked name.
And same thing, when user click on an item (a *day*) of the `DateListActivity`, the `NameListActivity` is started with the list af names linked to the clicked day.

Comment: I think you should go with commonsware's answer. You could probably cause a stack overflow unless Android cleans up the history, but if this requires thousands of clicks, then it's not an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So if the user clicks too much, he can
>   fill all the stack and the system will
>   throw a StackOverFlowException isn't
>   it ?

No, it won't.

Comment: Ok I probably misunderstand how works the stack, you are saying that even if the user do (`NameListActivity` -> `DateListActivity` -> `NameListActivity` -> `DateListActivity` -> ...) thousand times, the stack does not overflow ? Is it because its the same activities ? Can you explain a bit more please. Thx in advance

Comment: If OS will think it needs memory - it'll kill activities that it thinks needs to be killed. I think it's explained in details on one of the first video. Should be on youtube google channel

Comment: You appear to assume that activities go on the stack. They don't. They go on the heap. No extra stack space is consumed on a per-activity basis.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why removing the ability to go the Activity1 from Activity2 would deteriorate the user experience. I believe that you mentally create a hierarical list in your head when you navigate this type of menus, so when clicking on item22 I would get confused if I was sent back to Activity1.

I need more details about the content of the menus to suggets another design, but you might be best of rethinking the menu system.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, Android's "stack" of activities isn't a "stack" in the traditional sense, and memory is managed in a more intelligent way. The activities stack actually goes on the heap, and the OS will kill the activities lower on the stack if it needs to.

I would say the worst that will happen is you lose some old history.

If you want to test it, allocate a large amount of memory in each activity so that 5 or 6 will fill the available memory, then try it.

Answer (score 1):

commonsware is correct. You won't have to worry about a stack overflow. :) However, you can design the app to clear the stack to avoid the situation you described. Look into [Clearing the Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#clearstack), specifically the use of [clear top](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to store the history in some structure, rather than relying on the stack to maintain it for you.  Then you can maintain your good user experience and not blow the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this noHistory="true" and instead put   android:launchMode="singleTask" 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode
But Mark @commonsware you'll be fine as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar problems with my application.
Seems that the problem lies in number of nested views for each activity. So, if you have, for instance:

```
tab->
    linear layout->
        text,
        linear layout->
             text,
             scroll->
                  text,
                  linear layout->
                       image, 
                       text
```

and maybe several more nestings, the odds that you'd get stack overflow after getting from such view to a similar one and back several times (in my experience) are high. Check the nesting with hierarchyviewer (android-sdk/tools). Also tell me if you fix the problem, because I still don't know how to fix it...

Comment: This *is* a place where you can get a StackOverflowException, but this is all within one activity. The question pertains to having more than one activity.